# orderby and track by $index is not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have ordered a list and used `track by $index`. But it seems, list is not ordered.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="rfi in rfiList | orderBy:['name', 'status'] track by $index">
    <p>
      {{rfi.name}}==>{{rfi.status}}
      <button ng-click="search($index)">OK      
     </button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript part is

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rfiList = [{
      name: 'GHI',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'GHI',
      status: false
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF',
      status: false
    },
    {
      name: 'ABC',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'JKL',
      status: true
    }
  ];

  $scope.search = function(index) {
    alert('Index is=' + index + ' and value is=' + $scope.rfiList[index].name + '-->' + $scope.rfiList[index].status);
  };
}
```

What happened here is, in the `search` method, the rfiList[index] is not getting the value after changing the list order.

What to do for getting the values with the index after the list is ordered?

Here is the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twentyTwo/0ujns4cb/13/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rfiList = [{
      name: 'GHI',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'GHI',
      status: false
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF',
      status: false
    },
    {
      name: 'ABC',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'JKL',
      status: true
    }
  ];

  $scope.search = function(index,rfi) {
    alert('Index is=' + index + ' and value is=' + rfi.name + '-->' + rfi.status);
  };
}
```

and in your html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="rfi in rfiList | orderBy:['name', 'status'] track by $index">
    <p>
      {{rfi.name}}==>{{rfi.status}}
      <button ng-click="search($index, rfi)">OK      
     </button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Like the idea of passing rfi :). It should come to my mind :P

Answer (score 1):

The list is ordered in the front end part of your code because of the pipe / filter and not in the controller itself.

If you need the ordered list at the controller side, try sorting it in the controller itself.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code, It is working fine:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="rfi in rfiList | orderBy:name:status track by $index"> 

    <p>
      {{rfi.name}}==>{{rfi.status}}
      <button ng-click="search($index)">OK      
     </button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rfiList = [{
      name: 'GHI',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'GHI',
      status: false
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'JKL1',
      status: true
    },
    {
      name: 'DEF',
      status: false
    },
    {
      name: 'ABC',
      status: true
    }
  ];

  $scope.search = function(index) {
    console.log($scope.rfiList[index]);
    alert('Index is=' + index + ' and value is=' + $scope.rfiList[index].name + '-->' + $scope.rfiList[index].status);
  };
}
```